# Bootstrap Carousel Skipping First Image On Load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using a bootstrap carousel on my homepage and I had to use this script to make it auto slide(courtesy of Stack):

```
            <script>
                $(function(){
                $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                      interval: 4500
                    });
                $('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
                });
            </script>
```

However, when I initially load the page it instantly skips the first slide. Can I modify this script to make it wait to slide the first image? I'm by no means a JS expert so any help is appreciated.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is effectively clicking the "go to next slide" button:

```
$('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
```

Try removing it.

Comment: That worked but for some reason it didn't yesterday. Very odd. Either way thanks! Correct answer for you!